# Operations on the amount of values using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes 'transactions' and 'offsets'

offsets:

```
    Contact Account Name    
0   TODD HOWARD 
1   TODD HOWARD 
2   JEFF COX
3   JEFF COX    
4   TODD HOWARD 
5   JEFF COX    
6   MIKE BALDWIN
```

transactions:

```
    Contact Account Name    
0   TODD HOWARD 
1   TODD HOWARD     
2   JEFF COX    
3   JEFF COX    
4   TODD HOWARD     
5   JEFF COX    
6   TODD HOWARD     
7   MIKE BALDWIN    
8   MIKE BALDWIN
9   JEFF COX    
10  JC WHITE
```

What it want to do:
1) Is to count each unique values. For this purpose I've used:

```
df1 = offsets.groupby('Contact Account Name').size()
df2 = transactions.groupby('Contact Account Name').size()
```

And I've got

df1:

```
Contact Account Name
TODD HOWARD               3
JEFF COX                  3
MIKE BALDWIN              1
```

df2:

```
Contact Account Name
JC WHITE                  1
TODD HOWARD               4
JEFF COX                  4
MIKE BALDWIN              2
```

2) I want to merge both dataframes. I've tried `merge` but it didn't work.

3) I want to create another dataframe and to calculate percentage of the offsets out of overall transactions.

What result i want to see at the end:

```
Contact Account Name      Offset Percentage
TODD HOWARD               75
JEFF COX                  75
MIKE BALDWIN              50
JC WHITE                  100
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of aggregation is `Series`, so is possible divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df1.div(df2, fill_value=1).mul(100).reset_index(name='Offset Percentage')
print (df)
  Contact Account Name  Offset Percentage
0             JC WHITE              100.0
1             JEFF COX               75.0
2         MIKE BALDWIN               50.0
3          TODD HOWARD               75.0
```

Similar solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = offsets['Contact Account Name'].value_counts()
df2 = transactions['Contact Account Name'].value_counts()

df = (df1.div(df2, fill_value=1)
         .mul(100)
         .rename_axis('Contact Account Name')
         .reset_index(name='Offset Percentage'))
print (df)
  Contact Account Name  Offset Percentage
0             JC WHITE              100.0
1             JEFF COX               75.0
2         MIKE BALDWIN               50.0
3          TODD HOWARD               75.0
```

---

If need join both Series together call [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1, keys=('Offset Percentage','b'))
df['Offset Percentage'] = df.b.div(df['Offset Percentage'], fill_value=1).mul(100)
df = df.drop('b', 1).rename_axis('Contact Account Name').reset_index()
print (df)
  Contact Account Name  Offset Percentage
0             JC WHITE              100.0
1             JEFF COX               75.0
2         MIKE BALDWIN               50.0
3          TODD HOWARD               75.0
```